# Best way of clearing up URL hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Could someone point me towards on how to clean up the `#` inside URL?

I've currently got a popup which uses the `#` for reference, however when the page is refreshed the data isn't loaded because the data is only loaded when the user clicks on a button.

Currently happening:

- User clicks button
- Modal pops up (`#user-calendar`)
- User refreshes page, data is no longer there, modal still pops up because `#user-calendar` still exists

What should be happening:

- User clicks button
- Modal pops up (`#user-calendar`)
- User refreshes page, data is no longer there, modal should be closed.

I've tried things like:

```
setTimeout(function(){}, 500);
```

However with `setTimeout` etc the user still sees the modal then it closes. I want something clean, so it doesn't look messy to the user.

Anyone got any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for encodeURIComponent(str); ?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin Why would I need encodeURIComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the hash before the modal code runs. You could put this in it's own script tag above the script that makes the modal.

```
if(window.location.hash === "#user-calendar"){
   window.location.hash = "";
}
```

Comment: Hey, the modal still pops up even when I call this